# SQL string manipulation [Get all text left of '(']

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data which looks like so:

```
SourceOfBooking
----------------
Company1 (Foo)
Company2 (Bar)
Company3 (Foo1)
Company4 (Foo2)
```

I am looking to transform this, so my data only displays:

```
SourceOfBooking
----------------
Company1
Company2
Company3
Company4
```

I have tried:

```
LEFT(SourceOfBooking, CHARINDEX(';', SourceOfBooking) )
```

with no luck.

I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly simple... Anyone care to enlighten?

KR, James.

Comment: *"Incredibly simple"*: Yes. As incredibly simple as using the wrong search character ;-)

Comment: Remember to add a space before the `(` as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you've just put a wrong character

```
case
    when CHARINDEX('(', SourceOfBooking) > 0 then
        rtrim(left(SourceOfBooking, CHARINDEX('(', SourceOfBooking) - 1))
    else
        SourceOfBooking
end
```

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Thanks this works brilliantly, you've missed a "THEN" in your code though and it wont let me edit it in to include...

Comment: Accepted your answer. Thanks for the help, magical internet wizard.

Answer (score 11):

You can;

```
LEFT(SourceOfBooking, CHARINDEX(' (', SourceOfBooking + ' (') - 1)
```

(Remove `+ ' ('` if needed; it allows for rows with no  `(`

Answer (score 1):

This will return the company name whether or not there is a bracket, and will also handle cases where there is no space before the bracket:

```
select case 
    when CHARINDEX('(', SourceOfBooking) > 0
    then RTRIM(LEFT(SourceOfBooking, CHARINDEX('(', SourceOfBooking) - 1))
    else SourceOfBooking
end
from Table1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1c10/1)

Answer (score 0):

You cam simply try this.

Create a new table and insert the data as below scripts. Then execute the select query. You will get required output.

```
create table teststring
(name varchar(20))

insert  into teststring values ('ashish (123)')
insert  into teststring values ('ashish jain (123)')


select substring(name,1,charindex('(',name)-1)abc ,name from teststring
```