# Query to take the value after '/'

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose there is a value 842545/003. I need to take the part after '/'.
84454/02. I want a query to take the only 02 from here

Comment: it's duplicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899793/sql-string-manipulation-get-all-text-left-of

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL string manipulation \[Get all text left of '('\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899793/sql-string-manipulation-get-all-text-left-of)

Comment: @Diabolus I’m sure there are other *‘regex for last word in string’* questions, though I couldn’t find one for Oracle. The one you link to is for SQL Server though so won’t help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below substr() and instr() function

```
select substr('84454/02',instr('84454/02','/')+1,
length('84454/02')-instr('84454/02','/')) as val
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex (with the usual warnings about regex performance - the simple string functions like `instr` and `substr` are faster if you are processing millions of rows).

```
regexp_replace(yourcolumn, '^.*/')
```

This removes everything up to and including the `/` character (or the final one if there is more than one).

Answer (score -1):

If your are using SQL, you can use this.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('84454/02',PATINDEX('%/%', '84454/02')+1,LEN('84454/02'));
```

'84454/02'= Column name

Comment: The OP appears to be using Oracle SQL.